# SQLite CREATE TABLE and INSERT work, but return SQLITE_ERROR "no such table" C++

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

So this is my first foray into SQLite in C++ and I've got it all working but it's throwing SQLITE_ERROR - "no such table: (tablename)" errors.  I can't figure out what's going on - it shouldn't be throwing those errors when I'm creating a table right? I'm well aware that the table doesn't exist, that's why I'm creating it...

Handler object has a fn. that creates the schema if the tables don't exist:

`result = handler->createSchema();`

Which calls:

```
bool SQLiteHandler::createSchema()
{
    if(!isValid())
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(schemaExists())
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Create necessary table(s)
    std::string query = "CREATE TABLE symbols (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ticker, last_update, daily_data, minute_data, tick_data);";

    dbConn->executeQuery(query);

    if(dbConn->getStatus() == DatabaseConnector::DBC_SQL_ERROR)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Which calls (executeQuery(query)):

```
void SQLiteDBConnector::executeQuery(const std::string Query)
{
    if(!isConnected())
    {
        return;
    }

    //Execute Query
    char* sqlError = 0;

    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, Query.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &sqlError);

    if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //Error
        std::string err = "[SQLite Error]: ";
        err += std::string(sqlError);
        setStatus(DBC_SQL_ERROR, err);
    }

    sqlite3_free(sqlError);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried it without the ";" at the end of your CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: Just tried - still getting the same error.  SQLite syntax uses ;'s at the end of each SQL statement.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the statement, and the code looks okay. I'm not sure what `sqlite3_exec` returns, but `sqlite3_step` does not return `SQLITE_OK`

Comment: I thought that might be it too but I had it print the return code and it corresponds with SQLITE_ERROR (1).

Answer (score 0):

Here was the issue, nothing to do with SQLite, just an idiotic mistake on my part.  I was updating the status when an error occurred, but not when something was successful, so if there was an error it hung around.  I'm not entirely sure what triggered the first error but by changing this:

```
if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    //Error
    std::string err = "[SQLite Error]: ";
    err += std::string(sqlError);
    setStatus(DBC_SQL_ERROR, err);
}
```

To something like this:

```
if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    //Error
    std::string err = "[SQLite Error]: ";
    err += std::string(sqlError);
    setStatus(DBC_SQL_ERROR, err);
}
else
{
    setStatus(DBC_CONNECTED);
}
```

It's working.  That was pretty stupid of me :P